# TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_styled_components_primitives___default.a.div is not a function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, primitive, webpack-style-loader, styled-components

Primitives support (for) styled components is exciting... after install i get this error in the browser:

```
TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1_styled_components_primitives___default.a.div is not a function
Object.__webpack_exports__.a
src/App.js:13
  10 | })
  11 | 
  12 | //const styled = styled.default;
> 13 | const Body = styled.div`
```

This error does not show when import is set to import styled from 'styled-components' only when it is set to import styled from 'styled-components/primitives' here's the top of the **App.js** (from start to error line) made after running create-react-app.

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components/primitives'
import WebFont from 'webfontloader'


WebFont.load({
  google: {
    families: ['Bungee+Shade', 'Roboto', 'Nixie+One', 'Muli']
  }
})

//const styled = styled.default;
const Body = styled.div`
```

**Install/s seems ok???**

> yarn add styled-components react-primitives

```
yarn add v0.24.5
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
warning fsevents@1.0.17: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.0.17" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
warning Your current version of Yarn is out of date. The latest version is "0.24.6" while you're on "0.24.5".
info To upgrade, run the following command:
$ npm upgrade --global yarn
success Saved 2 new dependencies.
├─ react-primitives@0.4.2
└─ styled-components@2.1.0
Done in 118.88s.
```

Answer (score 1):

`styled-component/primitives` uses [`react-primitives`](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-primitives) under the hood to allow you to create truly reusable components like so:

```
const Wrapper = styled.View`
  color: blue;
`
```

This `<Wrapper />` component can now be used on the web, in ReactNative and can even be rendered to Sketch!

As you can see I wrote `View` there, and not `div`. That's because `react-primitives` chose to use a subset of the ReactNative primitives as the underlying unit of reuse, specifically these four APIs are exported as `styled.X` from `styled-components/primitives`:

- `styled.View`: A base component for Layout.
- `styled.Text`: A base component for Text rendering.
- `styled.Image`: A base component for Image rendering.
- `styled.Touchable`: A base component for interaction.

To use `styled-components/primitives` you'll have to use these four primitives to build your components. If you want to use standard HTML tags and are only building a web app you should use `styled-components` proper, but those components won't be reusable on ReactNative.

To learn more about `styled-components/primitives` read our [announcement blogpost](https://medium.com/styled-components/announcing-primitives-support-for-truly-universal-component-systems-5772c7d14bc7), for more information about `react-primitives` and why Leland chose these exact APIs watch [his excellent talk from ReactEurope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hNwQPJy-XZY)!